# Changing the position of editText in android when it's needed

Tags: java, android

As you can see from the below image, I create a number of edit texts using RelativeLayout(the layout is defined in XML) dynamically.

[image]

But the last edit text is unlike the other ones and I suppose that, this is because it just changes its orientation from horizontal to vertical, but how can I check it if this is so?

Comment: is the layout defined in XML? post it onto the question

Comment: Yes, I use RelativeLayout in XML. Also I have the first edit text defined in XML as the indicative one, so the other edit texts are created through code based on this first edit text

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working will bump it to the top of the active queue.